# Is it possible to take a screen shot of a file content using python

Tags: python-3.x

I need a python module or logic to take screenshot of a contents of each file which are present in a folder. I see PyAutoGUI, but it takes screenshot of the screen but i am unable to find a way to take screen shot of file content

Comment: open the file in the suitable application then take a screenshot?

Comment: I wanted to  create a automation script to take screenshot of files. So does python has a way to do it?

Comment: Content needs to be open in any application to get a screenshot.

Comment: I am able to using open os.startfile('result.csv') , and able to take a screenshot. As my file is huge, i want to open a file at specified line in python. How to do it?